# updating the the base storyboard images so all other storyboards are updated

Tags: ios, localization, uistoryboardsegue

My app is localized to many countries, i want to update the user interface with a few helpful images and good layout.

When i add pictures to the base storyboard or the English storyboard it doesn't seem to show on other boards, is there a way to change the user interface on one storyboard and it updates to all other storyboards?

I have a Base storyboard, but adding pictures to it, does not seem to add pictures to the French storyboard. However all the strings localize nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe when you add a new storyboard you can choose a storyboard to base it on, so choose a completed storyboard